# display server pdf file in android

Tags: android

I want to display server pdf on android without WebView or Google Docs.
currently I am using com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.5 library. but it's only allowed to display pdf form cache and storage. But I want to display external link.

I am already tried to display in WebView but it won't works.

Anybody have an idea how to do this?

Comment: you can have the pdf in memory

Comment: Download the PDF, then display it.

Comment: Download pdf will increase app data size. I have around 25 pdf files of min 15mb size.

Comment: `want to display server pdf on android without WebView `. Very good indeed. A WebView cannot display a pdf.

Comment: `am already tried to display in WebView but it won't works.`. Of course not. A WebView cannot display a pdf.